# How to add a border to a label in a Python VCL GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, vcl

I've made a simple `Hello World!` app in the [DelphiVCL GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiVCL4Python). "Hello World!" is shown on a `Label` on the `Form` as can be seen below with my code and screenshot:

```
from delphivcl import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500

        self.myLabel = Label(self)
        self.myLabel.Parent = self
        self.myLabel.Caption = "Hello World!"
        self.myLabel.Font.Size = 85
        self.myLabel.Left = (self.Width - self.myLabel.Width) / 2
        self.myLabel.Top = (self.Height - self.myLabel.Height) / 2


Application.Initialize()
Application.Title = 'Hello World'
MainForm = frmMain(Application)
MainForm.Show()
FreeConsole()
Application.Run()
```

[image: Python GUI Hello World App]

Is there a way to add a border around the `Label`? How would one do this?

I tried doing things like the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
self.myLabel.Stroke.Kind = "Solid"
self.myLabel.Stroke.Color = "Black"
self.myLabel.Stroke.Thickness = 1
```

Is it possible to add a border around a `Label`?, if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Label` component doesn't have a Border property by default, but there is a way. The easiest way to give a `Border` to a `Label` isn't to actually give a border to it, but rather to make a `Panel` component:

```
self.myLabel = Panel(self)
self.myLabel.Parent = self
self.myLabel.Caption = "Hello World!"
self.myLabel.Font.Size = 85
self.myLabel.Width = 650
self.myLabel.Height = 150
self.myLabel.Left = (self.Width - self.myLabel.Width) / 2
self.myLabel.Top = (self.Height - self.myLabel.Height) / 2
self.myLabel.BevelOuter = "bvNone"
self.myLabel.BevelKind = "bkTile"
```

[image: Python Hello World GUI App]